# Is it academic dishonesty and punishable if quizzes are reused in a retaken course (calculus)?

Tags: mathematics, university, self-plagiarism, policy

I am currently retaking a calculus course that I failed, and noticed that all the quizzes are exactly the same from when I took it. I do have the solutions to the quizzes, as I have looked over them when I completed them in the past. Does it breach any rules if I study the solutions and get everything right? Am I risking expulsion/punishment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem for the professor(s) running the course and not for you. Perhaps they have made a conscious decision to operate in this way. Perhaps they are just lazy. They might have the attitude that if you can do **these problems** then you know enough to advance.

While regulations about what materials can and can't be used while sitting the exam, I'd object to any regulations that forbid you any materials whatever prior to the start of the exam. If those regulations exist they are honey-traps that shouldn't exist. "Gotcha. I see you read page 45 in the text when I was clear you weren't allowed to go past page 44." Bizarre.

If you are learning the material from your study it is the purpose of the course. It isn't a game to be played with arcade rules, especially [Calvinball](https://calvinandhobbes.fandom.com/wiki/Calvinball) rules.

But if you think you need more of a challenge in the course, talk to the professor and ask how you can get it.

Answer (score 7):

It would seem that this is clearly on your professor, as students repeating a calculus class is a common situation. However, you would need to read the academic misconduct rules of your university carefully, as these rules can be counter-intuitive.

It might be best sending an email to your professor stating that you took the class before, have the quizzes, and apparently, the quizzes are not new, but that you have of course been reviewing the materials.